# What's the fastest way to logout GMail weblogins via an Android phone

Tags: gmail

Sometimes I log into GMail on a computer and after leaving the computer I notice that I forgot to log-off.
In those cases I don't have direct access to a computer but I have my Android with me. What's the fastest way to log-out? (Not counting the time for the initial setup)

Answer (score 1):

- Using any browser open https://mail.google.com
- Open the hamburger menu (3 bars on left). Scroll to bottom and select view Gmail in *desktop*
- Go to the top right and sign out
- **Create a shortcut:** If using Chrome tap the 3 dots menu and *Add to home screen* so that a shortcut is created on your home screen and you can jump directly to third step to sign out. On other browsers, this shortcut may be named differently